# Getting married or start my PhD?

Tags: nikah, men, education, human-rights

I'm in urgent need to get married. Recently, I finished my Master and now looking for job/PhD position. Before, I finish my MS: I promised myself that once I graduate I'll get married. But, so far, I'm looking for Job, and nothing is secured yet. I'm abroad for two years, was planning to go back to my family, but, I faced some visa issues, and had been returned back from the airport. Is there any sins if I delayed the marriage, until, Insha-Allah, find a job or something? If I started the PhD I may not find enough time (long vacation) to travel and get married there in my homeland, can I look for some woman locally and just get married, How about my family, If they disagreed about the Idea of getting married abroad; what to do?, or should I just stop everything (job hunting, my potential PhD ...etc.), and just go back to my country and get married?
Find a job or study in my home-country is too difficult, if not said impossible.
I'm afraid of Allah, if I attain some sins.

Comment: "*I promised my self*", when you promised yourself, I don't think it even counts. Anyways, if you're a male, to avoid falling prone to sin, it is highly recommended you get married first, either in your home town (or) marry locally by convincing your parents. Else if, you're a female, I don't know.

Comment: @azam If you look carefully, I mentioned : can I look for some woman locally, it means I'm a man :) , thanks.

Comment: Only you yourself can answer this question.  If you are able to get married, do so.  What about finding someone who has similar interests and can also do her schooling along with you?

Comment: Marriage shouldn't be tied to your career. There are good people everywhere. Dont worry so much about where or how but do worry about who you are marrying. Get to know them good first and I think knowing their family can predict alot about them. I love my wife's family for the same reasons I love my wife. Career choices are just a part of life that you and your wife will always deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I ought to mention that your question looks opinion-based to some extent. Although it can be replied by the significance of the marriage. Anyhow, your last sentence could be considered as the most significant point. I mean:

> I'm afraid of Allah, if I attain some sins.

In all probably or even definitely Allah will torture you if you delay your marriage in order to getting a higher degree! Although it is Okay to get a higher degree, but getting married (actually as an order of Allah) would be so more important than PhD. And indeed the actual earning of getting PhD is not worth in comparing with getting married. 
Furthermore, you ought not to be afraid of the poverty (if you have not a high property), since according to the Surah An-Nur: 32

> وَأَنكِحُوا الْأَيَامَىٰ مِنكُمْ وَالصَّالِحِينَ مِنْ عِبَادِكُمْ
>   وَإِمَائِكُمْ ۚ إِن يَكُونُوا فُقَرَاءَ يُغْنِهِمُ اللَّـهُ مِن
>   فَضْلِهِ ۗ وَاللَّـهُ وَاسِعٌ عَلِيمٌ ٣٢
>
> And marry the unmarried among you and the righteous among your male
>   slaves and female slaves. If they should be poor, Allah will enrich
>   them from His bounty, and Allah is all-Encompassing and Knowing. (32)

---

Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his family) said:

> There is no foundation in Islam which be as much as the marriage is
>   likable for Allah. (Namely: the marriage is the most likable
>   foundation from the view of Allah)

In addition, Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) said:

> You get married, since I’d glory (proud) to my Ummah abundance on
>   judgement Day…

Beside, Imam Ali (a.s.) said:

> You get married, Since the marriage is the Sunnah of the apostle of
>   Allah (Pbuh) .

---

**Conclusion:**

I strongly suggest you strive to get married as soon as possible, and hopefully Satan doesn’t deceive you to delay the marriage by the excuse of the PhD. Furthermore, I suggest you to come back to your country (if your fatherland country is and Islamic country) and get married there. And endeavor to get the consent of your parents too (in the marriage), since their consent will make a high praise in your life. Good luck / و من الله توفیق

---

**References:**

[tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/24:32)

[www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=106146)

[www.parsquran.com](http://www.parsquran.com/data/show.php?user=far&lang=far&sura=24&ayat=32)

Answer (score 0):

Always, get as much education as you can. In fact have life long learning in all areas of life. Marriage can wait, as your education may benefit you and your family later on, with better job.